# Is there any way to check if row is unique in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am working on a PowerBI dashboard where I had to compare two rows to check if it is unique or not.
For example - I have data like this

```
Book Number  
123456             
123456       
123456       
98765        
98765        
107563       
107563
```

I want result like this -

```
Book Number  Unique or not
123456       1      
123456       0
123456       0
98765        1
98765        0
107563       1
107563       0
```

It is easily achievable in excel using IF(A1=A2, 0, 1) but I am having hard time achieving it in PowrBI.

What are the possible ways to do it?

Comment: Your desired results don't line up with what you say you're checking. None of the book numbers mentioned are unique (assuming `107563` and `107663` are typos and you meant these to be the same), so they should all have `unique or not` = 0. What you seem to be looking for instead is an indicator if the row is the "first" in a group of rows with the same book number, but then you must at least have some way of ordering them by something other than a book number. Are there other columns?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, that was a typo. Thank you for pointing out, I edited the post. No, they won't all have 0 because in excel I am using if (a1(which is header name) = a2 (number), 0, 1) so, it will give the desired result as I mentioned and if use IF(A2=A3, 0, 1) still will give the result. No, there are no other columns to look for.

Comment: The problem is that while such logic is easy-peasy in Excel, it implicitly relies on an ordering -- namely the order the rows have in the worksheet. PowerBI/DAX is set-based, so rows are simply not implicitly ordered like that. You can *add* an order and then check if the row is first in its group, but you cannot check it against the "previous" row without that. The big question would be why this result would be useful to you in the first place -- what do you intend to do with the rows flagged this way? A simple selection of distinct values or a count per number might also suffice.

Comment: I am already doing the sorting in the PowerBI that's why these number are altogether. If it was in my hand I would be using the distinct function and not using a separate column to show values like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I updated this answer to include a sort before checking for duplicates. If you want the outcome to look exactly like what you show in your example above, then don't include the sort that I included, since it re-sorts the Book Numbers. But, you *will* need to sort them somehow before you check for duplicates.)

Here's a Power Query solution for what you show, rather than what you describe:

It starts with a table named Table, that looks like this:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Book Number", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Index] = 0 then 1 else if [#"Book Number"] = #"Added Index"[#"Book Number"]{[Index]-1} then 0 else 1)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

It yields this:

[image]

Comment: I would force the sort on the Book Number before adding the index.

Comment: Yes. And the key lines are the #"Added Index" and #"Added Custom" lines. The Index is used to reference the Book Number of the previous line, for comparison.